# CSS styles in mail body in Gmail

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

Does anyone know or can confirm if Gmail strips out style blocks from the mail body?
They [claim to allow style tags](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/#css_in_email) in the HTML body. However, in my tests style tags in the body were removed from Gmail.
I tested with this HTML, only the head style got applied.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h1{color:red;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Hi from H2-1</h2>
        <style>h2{color:green;}</style>
        <h1>Hi from H1</h1>
        <h2>Hi from H2-2</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Gmail-Css-Fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMCYT.png)

Comment: Use inline style.

Comment: The `h1` tag worked, why don't you put the css for `h2` also in the header?

Answer (score 2):

You have to do all inline styles for almost all major email providers.

```
<h2 style="color: #ff00ff;">H2 Title</h2>

<p style="color: #fff; padding: 10px 0; text-align: center;">This is a paragraph section.</p>
```

Comment: I just discovered an interesting case where I included the following inline styles in an element as part of an email sent to gmail: `style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 12em 6em 8em 10em; font-size: small;"` and what I found is that gmail seemed to have stripped out the "grid-template-columns" style for some reason, yet kept the other two. Why that would be, I'm not sure, but it just goes to show that even inline styles will not always come out as you might expect...

Answer (score 1):

Generally, working with html email is a massive pain.
All I can recommend you is to just run your html through some premailer, like: http://premailer.dialect.ca/. It should take care of inlining all styles.
There are no easy answers in the email land, it's still year 2000 there.

Comment: This premailer seems to work nice for putting css in <style> tags directly inline, which may be good in a number of cases, but inline styles seem to have limitations too.

Answer (score 0):

From my simple test, if you use [No-Comma Color Functions in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/no-comma-color-functions-in-css/) in your inline styles the whole `style` attribute will get stripped from that element.

This HTML

```html
<span style="background-color:rgb(239 68 68 /  1);color:rgb(255 255 255 / 1 );font-weight:700;margin-left:1rem;margin-right:1rem;padding:1rem;"> with slash without comma </span>

<span style="background-color:rgb(239 68 68 );color:rgb(255 255 255 );font-weight:700;margin-left:1rem;margin-right:1rem;padding:1rem;"> without slash without comma </span>

<span style="background-color:rgb(239, 68, 68);color:rgb(255, 255, 255 );font-weight:700;margin-left:1rem;margin-right:1rem;padding:1rem;"> with commas </span>
```

Looks like this in Thunderbird:
[image: Thunderbird html]

And like this in gmail (webmail):
[image: In gmail]

If using postcss, [postcss-preset-env](https://preset-env.cssdb.org/) should help.